# Properly testing ECC memory

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I am currently in the process of burning in a server that employs ECC RAM. I am not quite sure how I should go about testing the memory though. Normally I would let memtest86+ run for a day or so, but the error correction should be able to cope with a lot of errors without me even noticing them, right? Therefore I was wondering whether it is possible to find out if any errors did occur, but were corrected. Any pointers to other useful tests are also greatly appreciated.

In case it matters, my configuration is:

- CPU: Intel core i3-7100
- RAM: Samsung M391A2K43BB1-CRC
- Main board: Supermicro X11SSM-f

Comment: There is quite fine answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/643542/how-do-i-get-notified-of-ecc-errors-in-linux

Comment: If I understand the answer correctly, it describes how a tool from the main board manufacturer can log information about ECC errors. I do not see how such a tool could log error that occur during a memtest86+ as linux will not even be running at that time. Does the main board store the logs internally as well or am I missing something here?